# Cron Job appears to be working but no file is created

Tags: cron

I have created my first CRON job.  It appears to be working as the entry in syslogs.  It looks like, to me that the routine takes about a minute to complete.  This is in keeping with when I run the command manually and works great creates a file no problem.

The CRON job however fails to create the file and I can't see any clues in the log file.
I running Ubuntu version 12, here is a section of the log.  Where should I look next??

thanks

```
Sep 12 09:45:01 jasperSrv CRON[2523]: (root) CMD (/home/jason/jasperreports-server-cp-4.1.0/buildomatic/js-export.sh --everything --output-zip jas.zip)
Sep 12 09:46:05 jasperSrv postfix/pickup[1146]: 7734D200189: uid=0 from=<root>
Sep 12 09:46:05 jasperSrv postfix/cleanup[2559]: 7734D200189: message-id=<20130912084605.7734D200189@jasperSrv>
Sep 12 09:46:05 jasperSrv postfix/qmgr[1147]: 7734D200189: from=<root@jasperSrv>, size=75610, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 12 09:46:05 jasperSrv postfix/local[2563]: 7734D200189: to=<root@jasperSrv>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.58, delays=0.35/0.1/0/0.12, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Sep 12 09:46:05 jasperSrv postfix/qmgr[1147]: 7734D200189: removed
Sep 12 09:48:38 jasperSrv crontab[2582]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
Sep 12 09:49:14 jasperSrv crontab[2582]: (root) REPLACE (root)
Sep 12 09:49:14 jasperSrv crontab[2582]: (root) END EDIT (root)
Sep 12 09:50:01 jasperSrv cron[844]: (root) RELOAD (crontabs/root)
Sep 12 09:50:01 jasperSrv CRON[2600]: (root) CMD
```

Comment: I don't know if you're using absolute routes when creating the file You might be getting priviledges errors depending on the path you use. Or looking for the file elsewhere it's not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the logs it looks like Cron sent a mail to root with the output. Check that.

```
 sudo su
 mail
```

Also try using `crontab` as a normal user. This avoids using root privileges.

Comment: it's says mail not installed.  I shall install the mail and try again

Comment: it's created the file but has put it into /root folder

Comment: @user2247671; `/root` is the home directory for the `root` user. If this is `root`'s crontab, that's where it should put files by default. But does this cron job *need* to be run by `root`?